# standard expect works but xargs does not

Tags: bash, tcl, expect, net-snmp

I am currently trying to improve my script when using snmpwalk and wanted to incorporate using xargs as this would help me gather information from multiple devices at the same time. Taking small steps I created a simple expect file with the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set hostname [lindex $argv 0]

spawn snmpwalk $hostname

interact
```

From there I created a simple bash script to test the functionality of it with the code here:

```
#!/bin/bash

cfg=$(cat ./ips)

for c in $cfg
do

    expect ./EXPECT/01.exp $c

done
```

Doing this produces the proper information but takes time as it goes through each IP, one at a time.

I then commented the above code out and created the xargs version here:

```
#!/bin/bash

xargs -I ADDRESS -P4 expect ./EXPECT/01.exp ADDRESS < ./ips
```

Once I run the bash script, nothing is produced other then the command from the expect file echoing with no other action. I then looked into it and saw that you can add a "-noecho" switch to it but this didn't fix anything.

I then changed the spawn command to exec but the same issue happens and nothing is shown other then an echo of the command.

Would be interested to see what issue could be causing this.

Comment: It's not clear to me what the Expect script does. What should happen in the `interact` phase? If you are reading standard input from a pipe, and the `interact` step wants to read standard input, it will consume the remainder of the pipe.

Comment: You've written a script that only handles one argument at a time. No wonder that `xargs` (without the `-n 1` option) doesn't work well with it. Try printing `$argv` at the start of the script to see what might be wrong…

Comment: @DonalFellows With `-I`, `xargs` it will only run one argument at a time anyway.

Comment: Instead of `< ./ips`, try `-I ADDRESS -a ./ips`

Answer (score 0):

So the answer was rather simple and a bit embarrassing. The expect file needs some type of expect statement before it will run correctly. I simply put in the following expect syntax regardless if it would see this or not and it worked fine:

```
expect {
       "(yes/no)?" {
             send "yes\r"
             exp_continue
       }
}
```

From here the script worked as expected and it began to run 4 IP's at a time.